# Why are these simple functions giving me astronomically large or small numbers?

Tags: c++, math, syntax

So my professor asked us to make a program that will calculate a budget based on input pay rate and hours worked. The percentages were given by the professor. Also, I am very new to C++, so forgive me if this garbage.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
  int hours;
  double Pay;

  const double Net      = hours * Pay;
  const double Tax      = Net * .14;
  const double afterTax = Net - Tax;
  const double Clothes  = .1 * afterTax;
  const double Supplies = .01 * afterTax;
  const double Bonds    = .25 * afterTax;
  const double Parents  = Bonds / 2;

  cout << "Please enter hours worked \n";
  cin >> hours;
  cout << "Please enter hourly rate \n";
  cin >> Pay;

  cout << "Total Number of hours worked: " << hours << endl;
  cout << "Total income before taxes: " << Net << endl;
  cout << "Net Income: " << afterTax << endl;
  cout << "Money Spent on clothes and accessories: " << Clothes << endl;
  cout << "Money spent on school supplies: " << Supplies << endl;
  cout << "Money spent on savings bonds: " << Bonds << endl;
  cout << "Money spent by parents for savings bonds: " << Parents << endl;
  cout << "Remaining: " << afterTax - Clothes - Supplies - Bonds << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `double` for monetary values is wrong: [Money Pattern](http://www.di-mare.com/adolfo/p/money.htm).

Answer (score 3):

`hours` and several other variables are uninitialized, but you use their value to initialize the other variables. You need to rearrange the calculations so that they are performed after the necessary items have been input by the user.

Answer (score -2):

There isn't a value for hours or Pay when you first create the variables. So for example the statement net = hours * pay should equal to zero so that would explain why your results are probably inaccurate. Try switching the input functions to before the variable assignments and see if that does the trick

Comment: "should equal to zero"... no, the variables `hours` and `pay` do not fall into any of the categories for which zero-initialization is performed.